# flask restplus save file into DB coming from API

Tags: python, flask-restful, marshmallow, flask-restplus

I am using marshmallow and Flask Restplus for my one of API code where i have table with few columns i wan to post data into table using the POST method. In table i have one of column as BLOB which accept files JPEG or PDF and stores it into database.

I was able to save record into DB using the regular flask forms and now i want to enable to this functionality using the API.

For that I have bellow code where

**Expense Model.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from app import db,ma
from datetime import datetime
from flask import url_for, current_app
from app.utils.exceptions import ValidationError
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGBLOB
from marshmallow import  fields, pre_load, validate
from app.models.Person_model import PersonSchema
from app.models.ExpType_model import ExpTypeSchema

#This is model defination for the Expnese Table and its api calls with get post put all covered in here.
class Expenses(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Expesnes'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    per_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Persons.id'), nullable=False)
    U_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    Exp_per_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    Exp_type_name = db.Column(db.String(100),index=True)
    Exp_amt = db.Column(db.Float)
    Exp_img = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    Exp_FileName = db.Column(db.String(300))
    Exp_date = db.Column(db.DateTime,index=True)
    Exp_comm = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self,Exp_per_name,Exp_type_name,Exp_amt,Exp_img,Exp_FileName,Exp_date,Exp_comm):
        self.Exp_per_name = Exp_per_name,
        self.Exp_type_name = Exp_type_name,
        self.Exp_amt = Exp_amt,
        self.Exp_img = Exp_img,
        self.Exp_FileName = Exp_FileName,
        self.Exp_date = Exp_date,
        self.Exp_comm = Exp_comm
# Custom validator
def must_not_be_blank(data):
    if not data:
        raise ValidationError('Data not provided.')

class ExpensesSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        model = Expenses
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    u_id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    Exp_per_name = fields.Nested(PersonSchema, validate=must_not_be_blank)
    ExpType_name = fields.Nested(ExpTypeSchema,validate=must_not_be_blank)
    Exp_amt =fields.Float(required=True)
    Exp_img = fields.Raw()
    Exp_FileName = fields.Str(allow_none=None)
    Exp_comm = fields.Str(allow_none=None)
```

**Expense_Resource.py File**

```
from flask_restplus  import  Resource
import json
from flask import request
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
from app.models.Expense_model import Expenses, ExpensesSchema
from datetime import datetime
from app import db

expenses_schema = ExpensesSchema(many=True)
expense_schema = ExpensesSchema()


class ExpenseRes(Resource):
    # This is  method for all ExpTypes
    @classmethod
    @login_required
    def get(cls):
        exptypes = Expenses.query.filter_by(u_id=current_user.id)
        invtypes = expenses_schema.dump(exptypes).data
        return {'status': 'success', 'data': exptypes}, 200

    # This is new records creation Persons
    @classmethod
    @login_required
    def post(cls):
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if not json_data:
            return {'message': 'No input data provided'}, 400
        # Validate and deserialize input
        data, errors = expense_schema.load(json_data)
        print data
        if errors:
            return errors, 422
        expensetype = Expenses.query.filter_by(u_id=current_user.id,
                                               Exp_per_name=data['Exp_per_name'],
                                               Exp_type_name = data['Exp_type_name'],
                                               Exp_amt=data['Exp_amt'],
                                               Exp_date=data['Exp_date']
                                               ).first()
        if expensetype:
            return {'message': 'Expense name already exists'}, 400
        newexpensetype = Expenses(u_id=current_user.id,
                             Exp_per_name=data['Exp_per_name'],
                             Exp_type_name=data['Exp_type_name'],
                             Exp_img = request.json['binary'],
                             Exp_FileName= request.json['file_name'],
                             Exp_amt=data['Exp_amt'],
                             Exp_date=data['Exp_date'],
                             Exp_comm= data['Exp_comm']
                             )

        try:
            db.session.add(newexpensetype)
            db.session.commit()
            result = expense_schema.dump(newexpensetype).data
            return {"status": 'success', 'data': result}, 201
        except:
            return {'message': 'An error occurred while creating Investment Type'}, 500
```

How to save file in to database and how do i pass file pay load to my API.
Is there way to only allow JPEG and PDF file with size less 15 MB only to go

Thank you for your time and appreciate your feedback.